# What it wrong my query for calculating product detail views? (more than double product detail views from google analytics interface)

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, enhanced-ecommerce

I wanted to calculate product detail views, but I got more than double product detail views in query result than google anlaytics interface. Could you help me what is wrong with my query?

```
SELECT
--cast(cast(year as varchar) || '-' || cast(month as varchar) || '-' || cast(day as varchar) as date) as date_day,
--device.deviceCategory AS device_category,
prod.v2ProductName,
viewid,
count( prod.v2ProductName) as product_detail_views
from table_name,
UNNEST(hits) AS nested_data(hit),
UNNEST(hit.product) AS nested_data(prod),
UNNEST(customdimensions) AS nested_data(cd)
WHERE
hit.eCommerceAction.action_type = '2'
and MONTH=1 AND YEAR=2023 and DAY = 1
AND (viewid in ('96019039'))
AND (prod.isImpression IS NULL OR prod.isImpression = FALSE)
--AND prod.v2ProductName = 'kontakt'
group by 1,2;
```

What should be the accurate query?

Comment: when you remove the group by, you will find,  that you have to much rows on the hand as you make 4 cross joins and every row makes a Cartesian product with it neighbours